# How can I use Spring repositories and Jooq transactions together?

Tags: spring, kotlin, transactions, jooq

I am using Jooq for the persistence layer.
Also, I use `@Repository` annotated Spring classes to incapsulate logic of accessing to DB.
A typical repo gets the injected  DSL object and looks like

```
@Repository
class Repository(private val dsl: DSLContext) {

    fun select() {
        return dsl.select...
    }
```

The Jooq [documentation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/) explains how to use transactions with the DSL object.
In short, it looks like

```
dsl.transaction { configuration ->
    configuration.dsl().select...
}
```

If I want to execute several DB calls from different repositories this becomes a problem because I need to pass somehow the derived configuration to all repositories.
How can I nicely use Jooq transactions with `@Repository` Spring classes?

Ideally, I would imagine it something like:

```
class Service {
    fun someFun() {
        tx {
            repository1.select()
            repository2.update()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the @Transactional annotation is not applicable in my case

Comment: If you use a Spring MVC app, then Spring should have configured a JdbcTransactionManager (not sure about the exact name) plugged on the DSLContext datasource. injecting it and doing something like `transactionTemplate.executeTransaction { status -> repo.call1() ; repo.call2() }` should work.